# Параллельная обработка элементов массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

У меня есть многопроцессорная программа. Каждый процесс берет число из **`data`**, а затем вставляет его в **`__queue_out`**.

Но есть проблема: когда начинается последний процесс, начинается бесконечный цикл и все процессы просто **умирают**

Например: Когда queue.get() == 10000, то программа убивает все процессы и остается бессмысленный бесконечный цикл

```
import time
import threading
import random
from queue import Queue, PriorityQueue
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process


data = range(1, 100001)

start = time.time()
end_date = time.time() - start


class Worker(Process):
    counter = -1

    def __init__(self, queue_in, queue_out):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self._daemon = Process().daemon
        # self.setDaemon(True)

        self.__queue_in = queue_in
        self.__queue_out = queue_out

    def run(self):
        while True:
            job = self.__queue_in.get()

            Worker.counter += 1
            num = Worker.counter

            print('Получил: ', self.name, job)

            print('Выполнил: ', self.name, job)

            self.__queue_out.put((num, job))
            self.__queue_in.task_done()


queue = Queue()
res = PriorityQueue()


for i in data:
    queue.put(i)


for i in range(1):
    w = Worker(queue, res)
    w.start()

queue.join()

out = []
while not res.empty():
    out.append(res.get()[1])


print(out)
print(end_date)
```

Comment: Я случайно удалил ваш ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Внутри `run`, у вас стоит `while True`, но нет ни `break`, ни `return`, поэтому да, получается бесконечный цикл.